# How to join an SQL table from a .mdb file with a .db

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to join two SQL tables. The .mdb file I can open it in Microsoft Access, but the .db I can't open it anywhere. How do I join them? What are my options?
I've tried so many things...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

.db is a Generic Database format.
The following applications are capable of opening that format.

- Microsoft Access 2013
- Corel Paradox
- LibreOffice
- Synopsys Design Compiler Graphical
- SQLite